# Pithy summary for comonad. (Where a monad is a 'type for impure computation')

Tags: monads, category-theory, comonad

In terms of pithy summaries - [this description of Monads seems to win](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488646/why-are-side-effects-modeled-as-monads-in-haskell) - describing them as a 'type for impure computation'.

What is an equivalent pithy (one-sentence) description of a comonad?

Comment: Re the Haskell tag - thanks for the edits - I was honestly thinking of `core.async` in Clojure. Can we remove the 'haskell' tag?

Comment: NB: that summary may be pithy but almost completely wrong; so a true equivalent would also be almost completely wrong.

Comment: A use case: https://functorial.com/the-future-is-comonadic/main.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"A type for context-dependent computation"

Alternatively, a better "pithy description" for monads might be a 'type for output impurity', in which case then the pithy description for comonads is a 'type for input impurity'.

(If you are interested in comonads, some more introduction is given in some talks slides of mine: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~dao29/talks/comonads-and-codo-talk-dorchard-2011.pdf)