# How to implement function with side effects?

Tags: haskell, monads, side-effects

I am beginner in programming via Haskell language. I am interested at writing function in Haskell, which has side effects like this (for educational purposes, it can have another side effect):

```
-- function foo behaves like random numbers generator
foo :: Int
{- foo = some magic -}
-- It can print True or False
print $ show (foo /= foo)
```

As I understood, I have to implement some type instance of Monad with such behaviour (like this: IO [Why are side-effects modeled as monads in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488646/why-are-side-effects-modeled-as-monads-in-haskell)). But I really don't understand how to write simple example of function for this purpose.

Comment: hm, what do you expect of us to do? You've already figured out you need to learn to deal with Monads, so go and continue to read whatever intro to Haskell you're currently using!

Comment: `Int` is not the type of a function. It's just a number.

Comment: I just want to see examples, which show implementation of such behaviour

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you right you want to see how a random number generator is implemented in haskell under the hood?

Comment: Yes, as example some simplified version. As I understood, there IO type for implementing side effects

Answer (score 1):

If `foo` really behaves like some RNG, it must have some monadic type, or take as an additional input the state of the RNG.

Here's an example, using the system RNG (which lives in the IO monad):

```
import System.Random

foo :: IO Int
foo = randomRIO (1,5)  -- random number between 1 and 5

main :: IO ()
main = do
  x <- foo
  y <- foo
  print $ x /= y
```

In `main`, we simply call `foo` twice, binding its results to `x,y`, which have type `Int`. Then, we can compare them as usual.

Note that we can not use `foo /= foo` since `foo :: IO Int`, an action returning an Int, and we can't compare actions, only basic data like integers. This is why we first execute the actions, and then compare their results.

The `main` could be written in one line exploiting some more advanced combinators

```
  main = print =<< ((/=) <$> foo <*> foo)
  -- or
  main = print =<< liftA2 (/=) foo foo
```

but I would not focus on these at the beginning.

---

A more general example of a side-effecful computation:

```
foo :: IORef String -> IO Int
foo s = do
  x <- readIORef s              -- reading a "variable"
  print x                       -- output
  w <- getLine                  -- input
  writeIORef s ("qwerty" ++ x)  -- writing a variable
  length <$> readIORef s

main :: IO ()
main = do
  s <- newIORef "dummy"
  print =<< foo s
```

Comment: I know about System.Random. I just want to see some implementation of such behavior (for educational purposes, it can have another side effect)

Comment: @АлександрЛысенко I added an example... I'm not sure I understand what you really want.

Comment: I want to create own monad, which allows to create functions with side effects.

Comment: Look up `State` if you simply want to read/write variables. Or `ST`. If you want input/output, you need `IO` or `StateT IO`. `State` and `StateT` have their implementation available on hackage. `IO` can not be implemented except by using low-level "unsafe" primitives.